# Location transmitter

Tags: radio, transmitter

I want some advices about a radio transmistter,actually this radio trasmitter is more a location transmitter which transmits at about 512Hz.I want to know how could i design a transmiter and a receiver at this frequency,is it some ic that could do this or do i need to use some discret components ? With the receiver i want something like a device that show me when i am really close to the transmitter.It's called 512Hz sonde.
Example: https://www.ridgid.com/us/en/remote-transmitter

Thank you !

Comment: This is WAY too broad.  If you want to get an answer, add some application specifications.

Comment: Why such a low frequency? An optimal antenna will be many kilometers long. In fact it would probably be easier to find the antenna and track it to the transmitter, than to build a matching directionally sensitive receiver for it.

Comment: Ok,i want to have a device which is equipped with a radio transmitter which will be "inserted" in sewage pipe and i want to locate with a radio receiver from surface.All i want to know is when i am really close to the device. @jippie i saw some devices that operate at this frequency, i don't have any claims about frequency just to pass through ground(4-5 meters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i was looking is LFMC(Low-Frequency Magnet Transmitter).

A good application note : http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00232B.pdf